# How to find the location of the Android SDK on a hosted agent in Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: android, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'd like to build my android project on a hosted build agent in VSTS.
So I created an Android build definition, queued it up on a "Hosted Linux Preview" agent, and my build failed with this error:

> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the
>   local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable

As far as I can see, I have no direct access to the filesystem of the agent.
How can I find the location of the Android SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build android project you will need a build agent on which the **Android SDK is installed**. You may use one of the following:

> - The **Hosted VS2017** agent provided by VSTS, or
> - See Build and release agents for instructions on creating your own    Linux, macOS, or Windows build agent. **The Android SDK must be installed on your agent.**

There isn't the Capability `Android SDK` in "`Hosted Linux Preview`" agent.

Just check the agent **Capabilities** for the hosted agents: ( `Manage -> Agent Pools -> Hosted Linux Preview ->Click the Hosted agent -> Capabilities`). You can see the location of the Android SDK from the agent capabilities if it existing there.

So, you can use the **Hosted** or **Hosted VS2017** agent to build your android project instead of the `Hosted Linux Preview` agent.

Please see [Build your Android app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/mobile/android?view=vsts&tabs=vsts#prerequisites) for details.

[image]